# Is it bad to send a message to self() in init?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

In [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-applications-with-otp#working-on-the-workers) example, the author avoids a deadlock situation by doing:

`self() ! {start_worker_supervisor, Sup, MFA}`

in his gen_server's init function. I did something similar in one of my projects and was told this method was frowned upon, and that it was better to cause an immediate timeout instead. What is the accepted pattern?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update for Erlang 19+

Consider using the new [`gen_statem`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html) behaviour. This behaviour supports generating of events internal to the FSM:

> The state function can insert events using the action() next_event and such an event is inserted as the next to present to the state function. That is, as if it is the oldest incoming event. A dedicated event_type() internal can be used for such events making them impossible to mistake for external events.
>
> Inserting an event replaces the trick of calling your own state handling functions that you often would have to resort to in, for example, gen_fsm to force processing an inserted event before others.

Using the [action functionality](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-action) in that module, you can ensure your event is generated in `init` and always handled before any external events, specifically by creating a `next_event` action in your `init` function.

Example:

```
...

callback_mode() -> state_functions.

init(_Args) ->
    {ok, my_state, #data{}, [{next_event, internal, do_the_thing}]}

my_state(internal, do_the_thing, Data) ->
    the_thing(),
    {keep_state, Data);
my_state({call, From}, Call, Data) ->
    ...

...
```

## Old answer

When designing a `gen_server` you generally have the choice to perform actions in three different states:

- When starting up, in `init/1`
- When running, in any `handle_*` function
- When stopping, in `terminate/2`

A good rule of thumb is to execute things in the handling functions when acting upon an event (call, cast, message etc). The stuff that gets executed in init should not wait for events, that's what the handle callbacks are for.

So, in this particular case, a kind of "fake" event is generated. I'd say it seems that the `gen_server` always wants to initiate the starting of the supervisor. Why not just do it directly in `init/1`? Is there really a requirement to be able to handle another message in-between (the effect of doing it in `handle_info/2` instead)? That windown is so incredibly small (the time between start of the `gen_server` and the sending of the message to `self()`) so it's highly unlikely to happen at all.

As for the deadlock, I would really advise against calling your own supervisor in your init function. That's just bad practice. A good design pattern for starting worker process would be one top level supervisor, with a manager and a worker supervisor beneath. The manager starts workers by calling the worker supervisor:

```
[top_sup]
  |    \
  |     \
  |      \
 man  [work_sup]
       /  |  \
      /   |   \
     /    |    \
    w1   ...   wN
```

Comment: I would not recommend moving stuff to init/1 simply because it is usually repeated code. Sure, we could extract it to internal function, but then code in handle_call is less readable.

Comment: Well, if it is repeated code, you would put it in a function and then call it from both `init/1` and your `handle_call/3` or `handle_cast/2`. I see function calls as much more readable than sending  messages to `self()`.

Answer (score 7):

Just to complement what has already been said about splitting a servers initialisation into two parts, the first in the `init/1` function and the second in either `handle_cast/2` or `handle_info/2`. There is really only one reason to do this and that is if the initialisation is expected to take a long time. Then splitting it up will allow the `gen_server:start_link` to return faster which can be important for servers started by supervisors as they "hang" while starting their children and one slow starting child can delay the whole supervisor startup.

In this case I don't think it is bad style to split the server initialisation.

It is important to be careful with errors. An error in `init/1` will cause the supervisor to terminate while an error in the second part as they will cause the supervisor to try and restart that child.

I personally think it is better style for the server to send a message to itself, either with an explicit `!` or a `gen_server:cast`, as with a good descriptive message, for example `init_phase_2`, it will be easier to see what is going on, rather than a more anonymous timeout. Especially if timeouts are used elsewhere as well.

Comment: Good point about allowing the supervisor to start monitor the process. Perhaps behaviors should have had a `second_init` callback to begin with? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Calling your own supervisor sure does seem like a bad idea, but I do something similar all the time.

```
init(...) ->
   gen_server:cast(self(), startup),
   {ok, ...}.

handle_cast(startup, State) ->
   slow_initialisation_task_reading_from_disk_fetching_data_from_network_etc(),
   {noreply, State}.
```

I think this is clearer than using timeout and handle_info, it's pretty much guaranteed that no message can get ahead of the startup message (no one else has our pid until after we've sent that message), and it doesn't get in the way if I need to use timeouts for something else.

Comment: If your `gen_server` was started with `gen_server:start_link/4` or `gen_server:start/4`, the registration happens before `Module:init/1` is called. Anybody looking for the `gen_server` under its registered name will be able to find it and send it a message that arrives before your own.

Answer (score 0):

This may be very efficient and simple solution, but I think it is not good erlang style.
I am using timer:apply_after, which is better and does not make impression of interacting with external module/gen_*.

I think that the best way would be to use state machines (gen_fsm). Most of our gen_srvers are really state machine, however because initial work effort to set up get_fsm I think we end up with gen_srv.

To conclude, I would use timer:apply_after to make code clear and efficient or gen_fsm to be pure Erlang style (even faster).

I have just read code snippets, but example itself is somehow broken -- I do not understand this construct of gen_srv manipulating supervisor. Even if it is manager of some pool of future children, this is even more important reason to do it explicitly, without counting on processes' mailbox magic. Debugging this would be also hell in some bigger system.

Comment: timer:apply_after is only a workaround but the real question ist if sending to self() in init is showing a fundamental flaw in the design.  Also gen_fsm won't solve this and is usually not generally to recommend over gen_server.

Comment: why fsm would not solve it? Whole point is to execute something and still be compliant to init/1 spec, which is expected to return state. So, we could return state and actually initial state executing previous heavy init.

Comment: @user4: because the state function will not be called right away only on call or cast or timeout.  Exactly like gen_server does.  You could trigger the initialization with a short (e.g. 0) timeout returned from init but you could do this with a gen_server just as well.

Comment: exactly, but in fsm it is part of well defined behaviour

Comment: And what exactly is not well defined in gen_server about this.

Comment: well, this discussion does not make any sense, but to be clear: calling some function after defined timeout is not well defined in gen_srv. Where in fsm, we expect another state after given timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't see a point in splitting initialization. Doing heavy lifting in `init` does hang supervisor, but using `timeout/handle_info`, sending message to `self()` or adding `init_check` to every handler (another possibility, not very convenient though) will effectively hang calling processes. So why do I need "working" supervisor with "not quite working" gen_server? Clean implementation should probably include "not_ready" reply for any message during initialization (why not to spawn full initialization from init + send message back to `self()` when complete, which would reset "not_ready" status), but then "not ready" reply should be properly processed by the caller and this adds a lot of complexity. Just suspending a reply is not a good idea.

Comment: Imagine a supervisor starting 100 children each doing a half second worth of network bound initialisation.  A minute worth of latency from the supervisor is bad, but clients can probably tolerate half a second delay from the gen_server.

Comment: @cthulahoops I can imagine that (not quite understand what is the nature of such connections though, 100 listeners?), but half a second is not CPU time I believe. So why not to start all 100 in parallel? It will be the same half second.

Comment: The aim is to start them all in parallel, but supervisor won't start the second child until the first has returned from init.  Hence it is useful for init to return quickly even if the gen_servers will block requests for a short time.

Comment: @cthulahoops Initialize all your 100 connection in parallel in supervisor's init and pass them as a parameters to child specs. Did I miss something? You can even use child module for such init for proper encapsulation.